# Why is this elastic search query failing?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

```
curl -s -X POST "localhost:9200/usakeywords/keyword/_bulk" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{ "kwd":"zelda computer game","volume":170,"cpc":0.45116,"cmp":0.627}
{ "kwd":"nintendo zelda breath","volume":10,"cpc":0.195669,"cmp":0.6753 }
{ "kwd":"zelda","volume":550000,"cpc":0.231398,"cmp":0.3506}
{ "kwd":"link zelda","volume":60500,"cpc":0.402323,"cmp":0.2636 }
'
```

The response I get is...

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [2], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT bu
t found [VALUE_STRING]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Malformed action/metadata line [2], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT b
ut found [VALUE_STRING]"},"status":400}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The bulk API can be used for adding, modifying, and deleting records, so you have to alternate lines in the input: action, data, action, data. For instance:

```
{ "index": {} }
{ "kwd":"zelda computer game","volume":170,"cpc":0.45116,"cmp":0.627}
{ "index": {} }
{ "kwd":"nintendo zelda breath","volume":10,"cpc":0.195669,"cmp":0.6753 }
{ "index": {} }
{ "kwd":"zelda","volume":550000,"cpc":0.231398,"cmp":0.3506}
{ "index": {} }
{ "kwd":"link zelda","volume":60500,"cpc":0.402323,"cmp":0.2636 }
'
```

See the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html